# Attribute 'skipFirstLine' is not allowed to appear in element 'csv'

Tags: csv, apache-camel

I'm trying to use the skip first line and use maps in camel. I'm on version 2.17 or 2.17.0.redhat-630310 - it doesn't appear to work??? also, looking for how to use the use set maps option in xml dsl? thank you!

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:start" />
  <unmarshal>
    <csv skipFirstLine="true" />
  </unmarshal>
</route>
```

gives

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'skipFirstLine' is not allowed to appear in element 'csv'.
```

Also, can the csv.setUseMaps feature be used in the XML DSL ? thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `skipFirstLine` was removed in Apache Camel 2.15. Use `skipHeaderRecord` in Apache Camel 2.15 and newer. Refer [CSV DataFormat](http://camel.apache.org/csv.html) documentation for more details about available options.

But since you are going to use `useMaps` option, `skipHeaderRecord` have no effect and you don`t need it.

**This should be enough:**

```
<unmarshal>
 <csv useMaps="true" /> <!-- Make sure your CSV have valid header to use useMaps option -->
</unmarshal>
```

Comment: thank you again Bedla, I greatly appreciate your help, this is a great mentoring site also for us newbies. still trying to figure out how to accept answers?  not obvious unless i need new glasses. :)

Comment: @GLMills Still not accepted :-) Maybe this tutorial can help [How to update and accept answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers)? Or this animation [What does "accepting an answer" mean? How do I do it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65088/389339)